# remove CW status for this answer? (OO-principles for Javascript by Daniel)

Tags: support, status-completed, community-wiki, specific-answer

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/180588/31260

Above answer has been made CW per automatic rule ([quote source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/165773)):

> The post has been edited ten (10) times by the original owner.

Automatically applying generic rule in this particular case looks unfair.
<sub>In case of doubt, check the answer contents and revisions history to decide whether you agree with above.</sub>

- answer: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/180588/31260
- revisions: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/180588/revisions

Answer looks exceptionally good and revisions (all made by author) look like substantially adding a value.

Is it possible to clear CW status to recognize an extraordinary contribution of the author?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might be a good example of an unfair CW, every edit added something valuable to the answer and there doesn't seem to be a series of minor edits that would point to rep whoring. Furthermore all edits are by the answer's author, I don't see any reason to encourage collaboration, which is what CW is supposed to be about. Also, it's worth pointing out that the author continued adding valuable information to the answer even after it was turned to CW.

I'd like to wait a day or two to see if anyone objects, I might have missed something. If there are no objections, I'll remove the CW status.

Comment: +1 - Have my support. I'll wait for CW to be removed and then +1 him so he gets the juicy reps for the good work

Comment: at `+7/-0`, it looks like your plan has a solid community support :)

Comment: Looks like it's done. Thanks Yannis!